# javascript merge array if the inside objects are same

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement, merge

anyone online. I need a help. i have an array like this.

```
var array = [ {
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: 'Hot Water',
additional_facilities: 'Iron' },
    {
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: 'Minibar',
additional_facilities: 'AC' },
    {
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: 'cold Water',
additional_facilities: 'Fan' },
    {
roomNumber: 'R02',
roomType: 'standerd',
basic_facilities: 'View',
additional_facilities: 'Washing' },
         {
roomNumber: 'R02',
roomType: 'standerd',
basic_facilities: 'View 2',
additional_facilities: 'wash' }
    ]
```

i want to make it like this.

```
var result =[{
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: ['Hot Water','Minibar','cold Water'],
additional_facilities: ['Iron','AC','fan'] },{
roomNumber: 'R02',
roomType: 'standerd',
basic_facilities: ['View','View 2'],
additional_facilities: ['Washing','wash'] }]
```

I know this is a basic stuff. But i need a help with this. Thanks.

this is what i have done so far.

```js
 var array = [ {
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: 'Hot Water',
additional_facilities: 'Iron' },
    {
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: 'Minibar',
additional_facilities: 'AC' },
    {
roomNumber: 'R01',
roomType: 'Deluxe',
basic_facilities: 'cold Water',
additional_facilities: 'Fan' },
    {
roomNumber: 'R02',
roomType: 'standerd',
basic_facilities: 'View',
additional_facilities: 'Washing' },
         {
roomNumber: 'R02',
roomType: 'standerd',
basic_facilities: 'View 2',
additional_facilities: 'wash' }
    ]
    result = [];

array.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.roomNumber]) {
        this[a.roomNumber] = { roomNumber: a.roomNumber};
        result.push(this[a.roomNumber]);
    }
}, Object.create(null));

 console.log(result);
```

Comment: I have wasted more than 2 days now. im still learning. This is for my school project. I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: As always, please show what you've tried so far that isn't working if you want debugging help.

Comment: Edited with the parts i have done. Thanks. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to combine the items into an object while iterating, which is the right idea, but the method to use to do that is `reduce`: the first argument to the callback will be the value returned from the *last* iteration (or, on the first iteration, the initial value - the second argument passed to `.reduce`).

On each iteration, create an object at the `roomNumber` if it doesn't exist on the accumulator (the first argument) yet - then, push to the `basic_facilities` and `additional_facilities` array in that object. At the end, use `Object.values` to transform the object into an array of its values:

```js
var array = [{
    roomNumber: 'R01',
    roomType: 'Deluxe',
    basic_facilities: 'Hot Water',
    additional_facilities: 'Iron'
  },
  {
    roomNumber: 'R01',
    roomType: 'Deluxe',
    basic_facilities: 'Minibar',
    additional_facilities: 'AC'
  },
  {
    roomNumber: 'R01',
    roomType: 'Deluxe',
    basic_facilities: 'cold Water',
    additional_facilities: 'Fan'
  },
  {
    roomNumber: 'R02',
    roomType: 'standerd',
    basic_facilities: 'View',
    additional_facilities: 'Washing'
  },
  {
    roomNumber: 'R02',
    roomType: 'standerd',
    basic_facilities: 'View 2',
    additional_facilities: 'wash'
  }
];

const roomsByRoomNumber = array.reduce((a, item) => {
  const { roomNumber, roomType, basic_facilities, additional_facilities } = item;
  if (!a[roomNumber]) {
    a[roomNumber] = { roomNumber, roomType, basic_facilities: [], additional_facilities: [] };
  }
  a[roomNumber].basic_facilities.push(basic_facilities);
  a[roomNumber].additional_facilities.push(additional_facilities);
  return a;
}, {});
const result = Object.values(roomsByRoomNumber);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to combine array of basis of `roomNumber,roomType`.You can use `reduce()` and `findIndex()` to achieve this.

```js
var arr = [ {roomNumber: 'R01',roomType: 'Deluxe',basic_facilities: 'Hot Water',additional_facilities:'Iron' },
   {roomNumber: 'R01',roomType: 'Deluxe',basic_facilities: 'Minibar',additional_facilities: 'AC' },
    {roomNumber: 'R01',roomType: 'Deluxe',basic_facilities: 'cold Water',additional_facilities: 'Fan' },
    {roomNumber: 'R02',roomType: 'standerd',basic_facilities: 'View',additional_facilities: 'Washing' },
    {roomNumber: 'R02',roomType: 'standerd',basic_facilities: 'View 2',additional_facilities: 'wash' }
]

let mkeys = ['roomNumber','roomType']
let ckeys = ['basic_facilities','additional_facilities']
let result = arr.reduce((ac,a) => {
  let ind = ac.findIndex(x => mkeys.every(key => x[key] === a[key]));
  a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
  ckeys.forEach(key => a[key] = [a[key]]);
  ind === -1 ? ac.push(a) : ckeys.forEach(key => ac[ind][key].push(a[key][0]));
  return ac;
},[])
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution...

```
...
const result = [];
for (const room of array) {
  const processedRoom = result.find(r => r.roomNumber == room.roomNumber);
  if (processedRoom) {
     processedRoom.basic_facilities.concat(room.basic_facilities);
     processedRoom.additional_facilities.concat(room.additional_facilities);
  } else {
     result.push(room);
  }
}
```